# Библиотека визуализации javascript

Tags: javascript, визуализация, библиотеки

Добрый день.
Нужно очень просто и быстро нарисовать матрицу 2D,
и задать цвета клеток или как то их помечать(стены, преграды).

Для того чтобы хорошо изучить алгоритмы поиска пути минимальной(оптимальной) стоимости(A*, волновой и.т.д.).

Как это максимально просто и быстро сделать. Навороченная библиотека с кучей функций не нужна. Главное простота. Это только для себя делаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такую библиотеку очень просто написать самому. Я, например, на написание [вот этого](http://jsfiddle.net/WbNZ7/1/) потратил минут 10.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
var colorMapping = {
    1: '#ff0000',
    2: '#00ff00',
    3: '#0000ff'
};

var cellSize = 50;

var matrix = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        row.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) % 3) + 1);
    }
    matrix.push(row);
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

function draw(ctx, matrix) {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    matrix.forEach(function(row, i) {
        row.forEach(function(cell, j) {
            ctx.fillStyle = colorMapping[cell];
            ctx.fillRect(i * cellSize, j * cellSize, (i + 1) * cellSize, (j + 1) * cellSize);
        });
    });
}

draw(ctx, matrix);
```

Comment: Вот это подходит. Только canvas плохо знаю. Придется вспоминать.

Comment: C таблицей было бы проще.

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое для такой задачи, это взять обычный <table>...</table> и JQuery.

Или же еще проще, взять готовую реализацию: https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js/

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется простой таблицы будет достаточно. Кастомизировать внешний вид ячеек можно с помощью классов и CSS.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/px4ryrfr/

```
<table id=matrix></table>
```

```
td {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```
var data = [
  [   { value:3, color:"#9C6434" },   { value:6, color:"#1CB039" },   { value:8, color:"#A65279" },   { value:2, color:"#EC6B20" }  ],
  [   { value:5, color:"#C05381" },   { value:0, color:"#EE291F" },   { value:0, color:"#0377D6" },   { value:7, color:"#5364D3" }  ],
  [   { value:4, color:"#37AB9C" },   { value:8, color:"#F90DB8" },   { value:4, color:"#B60372" },   { value:7, color:"#FA50A0" }  ],
  [   { value:5, color:"#50DA9F" },   { value:1, color:"#874716" },   { value:1, color:"#6F5004" },   { value:6, color:"#39EAFA" }  ]
];

document.getElementById("matrix").innerHTML = data.map(function(row) {
  return "<tr>" + row.map(function(x) {
    return "<td style=background:" + x.color + ">" + x.value;
  }).join("") + "</tr>";
}).join("");
```